# Getting marks contribution based on sum not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario in which i am trying to calculate the marks contributed by each student when compared to the Total marks of all the students

**Required Output** :

```
NAMES     MARKS    SUM    Reqd Column (MARKS/SUM)
------    -----    ----   -----------------------
Roger      96       366    0.262
Sam        85       366    0.232
Ali        74       366    0.202
Nina       58       366    0.158
Mark       41       366    0.112
Steve      12       366    0.032
```

where **Sum = Sum of the marks achieved by all (i.e roger's marks + Sam's + ...etc)**

**I ran the following query** :

```
select T.name,T.marks,T1.sum,T.marks/t1.sum
from dbo.Total_Marks as T
cross join (select SUM(Marks) sum from dbo.Total_Marks) t1
order by marks desc
```

But the result is different it is

**My Result** :

```
    NAMES     MARKS    SUM    Reqd Column (MARKS/SUM)
    ------    -----    ----   -----------------------
    Roger      96       366    0
    Sam        85       366    0
    Ali        74       366    0
    Nina       58       366    0
    Mark       41       366    0
    Steve      12       366    0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing integer division, not floating point division, so the result is the floor of what you expected.

```
select T.name,T.marks,T1.sum,cast(T.marks as float)/t1.sum
from dbo.Total_Marks as T
cross join (select SUM(Marks) sum from dbo.Total_Marks) t1
order by marks desc
```

For more info, read the documentation on [T-SQL division](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175009.aspx).

Comment: Thanks that worked . Just curious is that type conversion specific to SQL Server or works for all SQL supported DB's too ?

Comment: I don't think that is standard, but other DBMS's support it, e.g. MySQL.